# WEBrick::HTTPStatus::LengthRequired error when accessing create method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a very simple controller set up:

```
class LibrariesController < ApplicationController

...

  def create
    @user.libraries << Library.new(params)
    @user.save
    render :json => "success!"
  end

...

end
```

Basically, whenever I try to access the create method of LibrariesController using HTTParty.post I get a WEBrick::HTTPStatus::LengthRequired error on the server. The method is not even being accessed! Here is the stack trace (this is the full output server side - notice that the controller isn't even being accessed):

```
[2010-04-16 00:35:39] ERROR WEBrick::HTTPStatus::LengthRequired
[2010-04-16 00:35:39] ERROR HTTPRequest#fixup: WEBrick::HTTPStatus::LengthRequired occured.
[2010-04-16 00:35:39] ERROR NoMethodError: private method `gsub!' called for #<Class:0x2362160>
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby_187/1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/htmlutils.rb:17:in `escape'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby_187/1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpresponse.rb:232:in `set_error'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby_187/1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby_187/1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby_187/1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby_187/1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby_187/1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby_187/1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby_187/1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby_187/1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby_187/1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby_187/1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby_187/1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:111
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby_187/1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby_187/1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    script/server:3
```

I'm running rails 2.3.5 and ruby 1.8.7. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 72):

I got this when I did a POST with an empty body.  I was using curl.

Something like:

```
curl -X POST http://url/
```

I added -d '' and it cleared up the issue.

```
curl -X POST http://url/ -d ''
```

In your case, you probably need to add some content to a :body => '' attribute in HTTParty.post

Comment: Is there anyway to do that without adding the `-d ''` to simulate NOTHING being sent, when I'm not sending anything anyways?

Comment: If you switch to a different web server, for example thin, it works without having to send a blank body.

Answer (score 8):

use `:body` instead of `:query` on post and put requests.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still relevant for Webrick or if that has been fixed but there is a know issue for the error you are getting [Read line 2 on this TODO page on RubyForge](http://simplehttp.rubyforge.org/files/TODO.html)

Have you tried `gem install mongrel` and running it with mongrel or other ruby server?

Comment: This is true - however, this message was written in 2008 and it also says that this error is "low priority." I wonder if I've configured something wrong...

When I run with Mongrel I get the following error:

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
  

Rendered rescues/_trace (178.6ms)
Rendered rescues/_request_and_response (1.5ms)
Rendering rescues/layout (unprocessable_entity)

Hmmmmmm...

Comment: Yeah you are right Chris, but that's the only plausible explanation I could wind for an error. However Mongrel error is less cryptic, I've seen a similar issue recently, when I was was working with sessions. What is your session store? and do you have session key and secret setup?

Answer (score 0):

I was too having the same problem, just now I have solved it. With me it was the problem of newline char in the request header value. As soon as the WEBrick server gets the request form browser or and other client it will sends the request to your application and immediately returns code 411 with`ERROR WEBrick::HTTPStatus::LengthRequired`.

So Before Putting the header value you can remove newline char that's all.